# Reading and Writing to individual bits in a 64 bit int.

Tags: delphi, bit-shift

I have to store up to 7 bytes of data in a single variable, and be able to read and write the individual bits. With 4 bytes this is a piece of cake, I just use a for loop and perform a bit shift to either write the bit or read it:

```
data : int64;

data := $01 + ($00 shl 8 ) + ($00 shl 16 ) + ($FF shl 24);

for i := 31 downto 0 do
     begin
          if ((data shr i) and 1) = 1 then ShowMessage('data bit was one')
          else ShowMessage('data Bit was Zero');

end;
```

This reads the bits out in the correct order.

However, when I try and use this method for more than 32 bits is seems to fall down:

```
data : int64;

data := $01 + ($00 shl 8 ) + ($00 shl 16 ) + ($00 shl 24) + ($FF shl 32);

for i := 39 downto 0 do
     begin
          if ((data shr i) and 1) = 1 then ShowMessage('data bit was one')
          else ShowMessage('data Bit was Zero');

end;
```

This does not output the bits in the correct order, the $FF seems to get pushed to the back of the stack. It seems to read bits 31 to 0 then bits 39 to 32. How do I overcome this?

Comment: In fact, I'm not sure if it does get pushed to the back of the stack, it seems to mess it up totally.

Comment: Mask it by `Int64(1)`.

Comment: Thanks; just tried, no joy.

Comment: Checked a few things, Its not the read back that is the problem, it seems to be the method of writing the data. It doesn't like: ($FF shl 32)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your constants are treated as Int32 values, and calculations work with 32-bit values, and casting to Int64 occurs after all calculations.
SHL executes as
`{Value shl (Shift mod DATASIZE)}`, where DATASIZE is 32, so {shl 32} is equivalent to {shl 0} for 32-bit type. Compare

```
  i64 := Int64($FF) shl 32;
and
  i64 := $FF shl 32;
```

(for 32-bit compiler, at least)

Just cast constant(s) to Int64 to help the compiler a bit.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean, so: Byte0...byte7 : int64; then:   data = byte0 + (byte1 shl 8) ... + (byte7 shl 32) ??

Answer (score 4):

Do you really use the Int64 representation? Otherwise, if you are only out for the bits, you can simply declare a proper type and use the usual set syntax. You can also use  Include/Exclude to set/reset single bits.

```
type
  T64BitSet = set of 0..63;

var
  data: T64BitSet;

begin
  data := [0, 32..39];  // set Bits

  for i := 39 downto 0 do
    begin
      if i in data then
        <data bit was one>
      else
        <data Bit was Zero>;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is really interesting, thanks for the answer, I'll check it out :)

Comment: Out of interest, I am using the int64 to hold a decimal value calculated as the result of a function, I then add an address header to this number, (shifted by 48 bits) Will this method still work if the 64BitSet has to hold a "real number"??

Comment: As both use the same memory size you can cast from Int64 to T64BitSet and vice versa. The RTL contains a similar example for 32 bit in Sysutils.pas: TIntegerSet

Comment: I'd be wary about casting. And there's potential for endian issues for cross platform. At least be very clear on the binary interop you do.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Logical_.28Bitwise.29_Operators) for the bitwise shift operators says (with my emphasis):

> The operations x shl y and x shr y shift the value of x to the left or right by y bits, which (if x is an unsigned integer) is equivalent to multiplying or dividing x by 2^y; the result is of the same type as x. For example, if N stores the value 01101 (decimal 13), then N shl 1 returns 11010 (decimal 26). **Note that the value of y is interpreted modulo the size of the type of x**. Thus for example, if x is an integer, x shl 40 is interpreted as x shl 8 because an integer is 32 bits and 40 mod 32 is 8.

This explains the treatment of:

```
$FF shl 32
```

The literal `$FF` is a 32 bit integer and this expression is the same as: `$FF shl 0` which is `$FF`.

You need the left hand operand to be a 64 bit type which is achieved by way of a cast:

```
UInt64($FF) shl 32
```